# Maximo Anywhere configuring/integration with Google Maps?

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Is there any possibility to configuring/integration Maximo Anywhere and Google Maps?

Refer to IBM docs on http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.0/overview/c_maps.html

Maximo Anywhere is configured to use Esri, a map service provider.

Answer (score 0):

No we don't have Google map support yet.